# how to select the particular HTML element which is part of a class and not all the elements of a class for JQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {
         $(".style1:this").mouseover(function () {
         $(".style1:this").animate({ fontSize: '22px' }, "slow");
         });
         $(".style1:this").mouseout(function () {
         $(".style1:this").animate({ fontSize: '16px' }, "slow");
       });
    });
   </script>
```

Here ".style1" is the class....i want the animate function to work only on the element on which the mouseover() and mouseout() event occurs. The code given obviously doesnt work but i am trying to show what i want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` belongs within the callback, not outside it:

```
$(".style1").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).animate({ fontSize: '22px' }, "slow");
});
$(".style1").mouseout(function () {
  $(this).animate({ fontSize: '16px' }, "slow");
});
```

You can also chain `,mouseout()` to `.mouseover()` to avoid having to repeat the selector at all:

```
$(".style1").mouseover(function () {
  $(this).animate({ fontSize: '22px' }, "slow");
}).mouseout(function () {
  $(this).animate({ fontSize: '16px' }, "slow");
});
```

Comment: Additionally, if it only needs be applied to one class element which has no other selector: `$(".style1").eq(n).ready(function...`

Answer (score 0):

if what you want to animate is the font and you don't need to support old browsers you can always do this directly with CSS

```
.style1 {
  -webkit-transition: font-size .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: font-size .5s ease;
     -o-transition: font-size .5s ease;
        transition: font-size .5s ease;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.style1:hover {
-webkit-transition: font-size .5s ease;
   -moz-transition: font-size .5s ease;
     -o-transition: font-size .5s ease;
        transition: font-size .5s ease;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

No need for JavaScript coding

Here is the example
http://plnkr.co/edit/sDGMOczKgFYiqlMQDTvF?p=preview